# Cannot overwrite columns in Numbers for iPad

Tags: ios, numbers

When i start writing text on my iPad in Numbers, **i have to stay in one column and can't overwrite the next column.**

For example: I write something in **Numbers on my Mac**, **the next column gets filled when i reach the end of the other**.

How can i manage this on my iPad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer:

> Tap on the brush-icon, and deactivate the last menu-entry.

[image]